# Embed font will replace or complete another embeding font?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts, embed, haxe

I have a swf A, which contains no font.

If I download into it the swf F1, which contains few characters of Arial, then I'll have the arial font embed into A, no problem with that.

But if, then, I download the swf F2, which contains other characters of Arial into swf A, will I be able to use all the embed characters font, only the F2, or only the F1 ?

I'd like to have a link to somewhere where this is explained, even in very technical terms : I wasn't able to find one.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT : After few tests, it seems that the player replace the loaded font... How can I merge them, then ?

Comment: So, there IS a way to dynamically load in a font at runtime - but I'm not sure if it's possible to combine two different partially-embedded fonts? That's an interesting question.

I've been working on a tool that allows users to upload their own .ttf and .otf files at runtime, then use those inside of my Flash tool - it's working now, but it was not easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can merge them. Fonts are treated as any other class. When you load an SWF into another SWF in the same app domain, colliding classes are ignored. You can use a different [application domain](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html) if you want the loaded SWFs to mantain their own versions of classes, but I highly doubt you can merge them on runtime.

> Every application domain, except the
>   system domain, has an associated
>   parent domain. The parent domain of
>   your main application's application
>   domain is the system domain. Loaded
>   classes are defined only when their
>   parent doesn't already define them.
>   You cannot override a loaded class
>   definition with a newer definition.